# c language file doesn't run on vsc

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I downloaded c extension pack on vsc and enabled all of it. But when I try to run code in c this message comes out and it doesn't work. This problem doesn't happen with python. What can I do to solve this problem? please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vaXV.png)[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBG5J.png)

Tried deleting expansions and download all of it. And checked launch.json file but didn't know what's wrong.

Comment: Please take some time to [read the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs). It will help you install and configure the needed plugins and compilers.

Comment: Besides your configuration issue, that code can never compile sucessfully. You are missing a mandatory header and your `main` function is not complete.

Comment: What is *specifically* wrong with the launch.json file is that there **is** no configuration. Trying to launch *nothing* fails, telling us that the *nothing* is not a program it can run.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/1E5GdGxPf) is a `Hi World` program for you to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C files aren't "run" directly in VSCode like Python files are. Even if you have a compiler installed, it still wouldn't run right away.

To compile a simple `main.c`, in the terminal you can use GCC like this:

```bash
gcc ./main.c -o main.exe
```

This would create a `main.exe` in the same folder. You can then run it like this:

```bash
./main.exe
```

But when files increase and you have to make multiple "libraries" of header files, this method becomes very complicated.

Alternatively you can try my VSCode extension that takes care of all the build configurations, running, debugging etc and also helps you create new, multi-library projects.

It's called [C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit)